# Can't make my input fields sticky

Tags: php, html

I am trying to making sticky form. To be nice feature for end users, especially if they are requiring them to resubmit a form (for instance, after filling it out incorrectly in the first place).

This is how I do it.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])) echo htmlentities($_POST['name']); ?>">
```

Its working for me. But my problem is if I use `required` attribute for this `INPUT`, its not echoing `VALUE` in the input. But still I can see its value is available when I check it using firebug.

NOTE: It also happen when I using a validation plugin like [this](http://formvalidation.io/validators/).

Can anybody know whats the problem here? 
Hope somebody may help me out. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])){ echo htmlentities($_POST['name']); }?>
```